# Clean URLs issue using .htaccess in PHP project

Tags: apache, htaccess, webserver, http-code-500, configuration

I am working on a PHP laravel project. I am currently facing issues with *.htaccess* file. I have following *.htaccess*:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I reload my page the it gave me following error:

```
404 Not Found

The requested URL /contacts was not found on this server.
```

Then I opened `/etc/apache2/users/username.conf` file which had following line of code:

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In above code I changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. Then I reload page and got following error:

```
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /contacts on this server.
```

When I add `FollowSymLinks` to *.htaccess* file `Options` such as like this `Options -MultiViews FollowSymLinks`. Then sometimes I get this *500 Internal Server Error* error and sometime this *Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data*. Each time I reload my page one of these errors with `FollowSymLinks` option.

I also uncomment following lines in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

and still I am getting same permission denied error.

Please help me I am trying to solve this problem for past 3 days but it is till unresolved.

Comment: Can anyone help me out? Please help

Answer (score 1):

403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /contacts on this server

Ensure that folders Users, username and Sites are chmod 755

```
chmod -R 755 /home
```

Answer (score 1):

Please verify if `/contacts` exists with a folder permission of 755. The files under `/contacts` should have a permission of 644.

Also rename your current *.htaccess* file and create a new *.htaccess* file with the following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, set `Allowoverride` as `None` in the *.conf* file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to remove the `.php` extension, so I'll give the *.htaccess* code to accomplish that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

That should be located in the root directory.

So suppose there is a file in the root folder named *index.php*, you can then access it at: *site/index*. And if there is a folder called *contact* with a file in it called *contactnow*, then you can access it at: *site/contact/contactnow*

I hope you understood how this code works.